# Is there a faster way to diagonalize this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I'm asked to diagonalize this matrix for homework: $$\left[\begin{matrix}3&0&0&0\\ 0&2&0&0\\ 0&0&2&0\\1&0&0&3 \end{matrix}\right]$$ But since it's already almost diagonalized except for that $1$ entry, is it legit to say that we could row reduce and still have the same matrix except the 1 entry is gone? Because by simply taking the $4th$ row and subtracting $3$ times the first row we get the same exact matrix less the $1$ entry. But I'm not sure if that's a "legal" mathematical action. I wouldn't think so but I want to ask before I spend a bunch of time finding eigenvalues and determinants.

Comment: Since your matrix is triangular, you shouldn't have much trouble finding the eigenvalues. (The eigenvectors also require very little effort.)

Comment: in general, row reduction doesn't preserve eigenvalues. every nonsingular $n\times n$ matrix row reduces to the identity, but obviously not every nonsingular $n\times n$ matrix has an eigenvalue of 1 with multiplicity $n$.

Comment: To complement what symplectomorphic said, The problem with Gaussian elimination (or "row reduction") is that it operates by multiplying only on the left, while matrix similitude requires the matrix to be "sandwiched". That is, if you have a matrix $A$, then after one step of the elimination algorithm you will have a matrix $A'=EA$, where $E$ is an invertible matrix. This needs not be similar to the matrix $A$, because that would mean that $A'=EAE^{-1}$.

Comment: To perform operations which do not destroy matrix similitude, you need to apply to the columns the inverse of the operation you applied to the rows. For example, if you switch row $i$ and row $j$, you need to later switch column $i$ and column $j$ too. This is the kind of operation @MaMing suggests below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're out of luck.  This matrix is not diagonalizable.

Comment: Too bad it didn't come with a spoiler alert, but thanks anyway!

Comment: Well, you still have to justify this statement :)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: After rearranging, it suffices to consider diagonalizing $\pmatrix{3&0\\1&3}$, which is not possible.

Comment: Whoa whoa whoa... Why? I see that you took the four corners and put it as a matrix, but why can you do that?

Comment: @Kyle Rearranging row and column at the same time is something as $A\mapsto P^{-1}AP$.

Answer (score 0):

Since this matrix is triangular, (which represent an endomorphism $f$), then its eigenvalues are the entries on its diagonal i.e. $3,2,2,3$ and if we denote by $\mathcal{B}=(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4)$ the standard basis then $e_2$, $e_3$ and $e_4$ are eigenvectors associated to the eigenvalues $2,2$ and $3$ respectively.

Now if this matrix is diagonalisable then there's an eigenvector $$v=a_1e_1+a_2e_2+a_3e_3+a_4e_4$$
such that $f(v)=3v$ and we can verify easly that this equality is impossible, hence this matrix isn't diagonalisable.

Comment: Conclusion correct, but argument flawed. $a_i=0$ for $i=1,2,3$ and $a_4=1$ satisfy equality.